# Error executing shell command in pig

Tags: shell, apache-pig

So I am trying to do something like:

```
%DECLARE Variable `cat src/documents/item.json`;
Filter BY field = Variable;
```

But I am getting an error saying:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - java.lang.RuntimeException: Error executing shell command: Command exit with exit code of 1
```

Can someone suggests what's wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely "src/documents/item.json" doesn't exist and failing.

Interesting that I fixed
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-5349
just today that would have shown proper error message in addition to the exit code.

With that change, it should print out something like

"cat: src/documents/item.jsonl: No such file or directory"

Comment: Thought I have included it but somehow forget to include it. Thanks!